# Iterate two arrays: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to iterate over two arrays, states and districts, but I get an error-message saying "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". I don't know what's causing it.

This is my code:

```
var estados = [ "aguascalientes", "baja-california", "baja-california-sur", 
                "yucatan", "zacatecas", ]; 
var municipios = [ [ "aguascalientes", "asientos", "calvillo", "cosio", "tepezala" ], 
                   [ "mexicali", "playas-de-rosarito", "ensenada" ] ];

$("#property_location").change(function () {
    $( "#property_location option:selected" ).each(function() {
        var i;
        var j;
        for (i = estados.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            if ($( this ).val() == estados[i]) {
                console.log(estados[i]);

                for (j = municipios[i].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    $("#property_municipio option[value='"+municipios[i][j]+"']").show();    
                }

            } else {

                for (j = municipios[i].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    $("#property_municipio option[value='"+municipios[i][j]+"']").hide();    
                }    
            }
        }
    });
}).change();
```

Comment: please add the arrays you iterating.

Comment: The are the arrays :

var estados = [
        "aguascalientes",
        "baja-california",
        "baja-california-sur",
        "yucatan",
        "zacatecas",
    ];

    var municipios = [
        [
            "aguascalientes",
            "asientos",
            "calvillo",
            "cosio",
            "tepezala"           
        ],
        [
            "mexicali",
            "playas-de-rosarito",
            "ensenada"
        ]
    ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `estados` has more member than `municipios` you loop trough every member of `estados` and check how many member does the `municipios` sub array have.

```
for (j = municipios[i].length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

if `i` is greater than `1` `municipios[i]` is undefined and you can't calculate the length of undefined. this generate your error.

By the way, you overwrite your loop index `i` if you use it in both loops.
Please use it like that:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   ...
   for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: You are cool. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first/top array is having 5 elements as I see, while the second array municipios is having 2 elements( ofcourse the nested lists are having data, but the actual length will be 2 as is it containing only 2 lists).
 While the outer loop is working fine, the issue is with the inner loop. When i reaches greater than 2, suppose 3, the code is trying to fetch the 3rd element from municipios array, which does not even exist. Moreover, its trying to access that particular elements' length.

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem has been solved.